Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
I build a SSR project using webpack and it runs totally fine. But when I apply SCSS in my project, it give me an error:

ERROR in ./src/client/styles/Calculator.scss 1:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
h1 {
color: aqua;
| }
 @ ./src/client/pages/Calculator.tsx 40:0-35
 @ ./src/client/App.tsx 3:0-44 13:33-43
 @ ./src/server/server.tsx 9:0-32 23:40-43


I put the webpack config and package.json below:
webpack.config.cjs
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const babelLoader = {
  test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }]]
    }
  }
}

const scssLoader = {
  test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}

const resolve = {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.scss']
}

const serverConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/server/server.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'server.cjs'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [babelLoader]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      PORT: 3000
    })
  ],
  resolve
}

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/static',
    filename: 'client.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [babelLoader, scssLoader]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: `${__dirname}/src/client/index.html`
    })
  ],
  resolve
}

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig]

package.json
{
  "name": "udt-react-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/server.cjs",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "husky",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.26.0",
    "@eslint/js": "^9.14.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "eslint": "^9.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.3",
    "husky": "^9.1.6",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.10",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.2",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.80.6",
    "sass-loader": "^16.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.5",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.10",
    "tsx": "^4.19.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "webpack": "^5.96.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}

I know the reason is it doesn't process SCSS file, but I have installed sass-loader and put it in webpack.config.cjs but still have the error.

Try changing module: { rules: [babelLoader] }, to module: { rules: [babelLoader, scssLoader] }, in webpack config serverConfig

OMG its work! Thank you very much!
